# Intercept the Quote Billing Address

Tags: apex, quote, urlhacking, address

I'm using the standard Salesforce quote feature to generate quotes for opportunities.

My opportunity has a picklist on it which provides two billing address options (one being to use the original opportunity billing address, the other being a custom address).

As soon as the "New Quote" button is pressed, I am presented with the quote form, with the opportunity account billing address pre-populated in the "Address Information". Is there anywhere I can hook into this process to write up my logic to inject the required address (based on the picklist).

I'm fully capable with Apex/Triggers/Clicks etc. but just don't know what point I can take control of this button click? Is the Address Information configurable? Or am I going to be faced with producing a custom button for "New Quote" and all that entails..

Answer (score 1):

Simon,

See below link. I did inspect element to find the field id, "ShippingAddressstreet" and used that in the URL and it worked fine. You can get other field ids to populate the values. You will have to use custom javascript button or custom VF page to override the standard "New" functionality.

https://csxx.salesforce.com/0Q0/e?retURL=%2F006Z000000xxxxx&oppid=006Z000000xxxxx&ShippingAddressstreet=test

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. Thank you. I will look into this idea a bit closer today.

Answer (score 0):

While officially unsupported, you can make use of a well documented technique known as URL hacking to provide default values on the new Quote page.  The following websites do a pretty great job explaining the concepts and techniques

- [Salesforce URL Hacking to Prepopulate Fields on a Standard Page Layout](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html)
- [URL Hacking 101: An Easy Way to Streamline Processes in Salesforce](http://www.slideshare.net/Configero/configero-presentation-atlanta-user-group-nov-2011)

In your case you'd want to create a custom quote list button that using merge fields to pull down the appropriate address based on the opportunity picklists.  Add that to the quote related list for your opportunity page layout and then hide the standard one.